# Is my query correct how to pass parameter in Postgres SQL stored procedure functions

Tags: php, postgresql, parameter-passing, stored-functions

I am struggling with **how to pass parameter to stored procedure functions** in **Postgres sql**. Is my query correct? I get error *is invalid input syntax for type date: "Firstdate"*.What am I missing? Please advise me

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prisonparam(dvn_cd text,
       phc_cd  text,
       Firstdate Date,
       Seconddate Date,
       To Date) 
     RETURNS table (round text,sc bigint,scupto bigint)
     AS $$
     /* query start */
    WITH a
   AS (
       SELECT
        round AS round
       ,Sum(ben_sc) AS SC

       FROM prison_issue
       WHERE (
        DATE BETWEEN 'Firstdate'
            AND 'To'
             )
       AND dvn_cd = 'dvn_cd'
       AND phc_cd = 'phc_cd'

       GROUP BY round ORDER BY round
       )
       ,b
      AS (
     SELECT round AS round_up
     ,Sum(ben_sc) AS SC_up


     FROM prison_issue
     WHERE (
        DATE BETWEEN 'Seconddate'
            AND 'To'
           )
    AND dvn_cd = 'dvn_cd'
    AND phc_cd = 'phc_cd'
    GROUP BY round ORDER BY round
         )
   SELECT b.round_up AS round
  ,coalesce(a.sc, 0) AS SC
  ,coalesce(b.sc_up, 0) AS SCUPTO

  FROM a
  RIGHT JOIN b ON a.round = b.round_up
  /* query end*/
  $$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't double-quote parameters.

```
 DATE BETWEEN 'Firstdate'
        AND 'To'
```

is trying to use `'Firstdate'` and `'To'` as *literals*.

Don't quote them.

```
 DATE BETWEEN Firstdate
        AND To
```

or if you must use possibly problematic identifiers like `To` as variables, you should double quote them. But if you do so, do so *everywhere*, including the parameter declaration list.

```
 DATE BETWEEN Firstdate
        AND "To"
```

Comment: sir function created successfully.now problem is calling function code...include('connection.php');
echo  $hud='15';
 echo $phc='80001';
 
 echo $Firstdate='2015-08-01';
 echo $Seconddate='2015-10-31';
 echo $To='2015-10-31';
$dvn_sql =<<<EOF
      select * from prisonparam($hud,$phc, $Firstdate,$Seconddate,$Todate);
EOF;

$dvn_ret = pg_query($db, $dvn_sql);
   if(!$dvn_ret){
      echo pg_last_error($db);
      exit;
   } 
   while($row = pg_fetch_array($dvn_ret)){   
  echo $ben_st=trim($row['sc']);
   echo $round=trim($row['scupto']);
   }

Comment: boss function created

Comment: error is ERROR: function prisonparam(integer, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist LINE 1: select * from prisonparam(15,80001, 2015-08-01,2015-10... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Please open a new question for a new topic